# R file not knitting

Tags: r

[image: Screenshot of my issue]

Trying to knit my R file into a pdf? It says the following error message but I dont even have learnr in my library? Really not sure what to do.
The markdown file runs fine, it just wont knit. Any suggestions

I tried downloading the tinytex package but still no luck. Tried installing and loading the tidyverse package and that didnt work either.

This following code seems to be the issue:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(psych)
library(apaTables)
library(ggplot2)
library(sandwich)
library(remotes)
library(discovr)
library(ggfortify)
library(papaja)
library(apaTables)
```

```
data <-readr::read_csv("C:\\Users\\Licensed\\OneDrive -Copper Beech\\Uni\\diss\\Diss\\data\\happy_data.csv")

#data <- readr::read_csv("data/happy.data_csv")
```

Comment: It would be better if you could put a reproducible example. It is difficult to help you with the information you provided.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What kind of information could be helpful? Sorry Im not very good with stuff like this, evidently

Comment: If you could provide the content of your Rmarkdown with fake data, that would be perfect. Also, you errors seems to be related to the loading of the R package learnr. Do you have a bug when you write library(learnr)? It would be better if you could provide code instead of a picture.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience with me. My code is just short of 700 lines long, should i just add an aspect of it? Or should I add all of it? And no, theres no bug when i write library(learnr). Thank you :)

Comment: You should provide the part of your code for which there is a bug and you should provide information in a way that we can replicate your bug easily. We do not need all your code.

Comment: I have just added it to the original post. Thank you again

Comment: You should provide this code in form of text and not as a picture. If I want to replicate your bug, I can't use a copy and paste. I have to look at your picture and I have to type all your code which is time consuming.

Comment: I think I have added it, I copy and pasted it onto the original post. I will add it here too: `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(psych)
library(apaTables)
library(ggplot2)
library(sandwich)
library(remotes)
library(discovr)
library(ggfortify)
library(papaja)
library(apaTables)
data <-readr::read_csv("C:\\Users\\Licensed\\OneDrive -Copper Beech\\Uni\\diss\\Diss\\data\\happy_data.csv")

#data <- readr::read_csv("data/happy.data_csv")`

Comment: Is it possible that you want to use the R package discoveR instead of discovr? In your code, you use discovr.

Comment: @EmmanuelHamel, can you post as an answer (and explain how you guessed the problem)?

Comment: Yes, I will do. Also, Ella, welcome to the amazing R community of Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I ran

```
library(tidyverse)
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(psych)
library(apaTables)
library(ggplot2)
library(sandwich)
library(remotes)
library(discovr)
library(ggfortify)
library(papaja)
library(apaTables)
```

in a Rmarkdown and the R package discovr was not installed on my computer. When I tried to install the R package discovr, it seemed that no R package with this name was available. I checked on google to see if there was a typing mistake in the name discovr and I found the R package discoveR. I suggested to use the R package discoveR instead of discovr.

Comment: OK, thanks. Weird that this doesn't match the error indicated by the OP, but I suspect there is some non-reproducible weirdness going on somewhere ...

Comment: It is possible. It is hard to tell ;)